# createCloseAccountInstruction() question

Tags: spl-token

Can you issue a createTransferInstruction() then a createCloseAccountInstruction() in the same transaction? Like for instance if you had an NFT exchange like MagicEden, can they transfer an NFT and close the Associated Token Account in the same transaction? Ideally wanted to do in the same one since Phantom Wallet warns if you try to do more than 1 transaction at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
You can add both instructions to the same transaction.